# Authentication and save their data telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot

In my bot script, I authenticate the user with two keys that he enters and then use them to get information. The problem is that every new user who enters the message changes the keys for all users who communicate with the bot in telegram, how to solve the problem, the use of the database is not possible. Think about using the user class from which to write data to the created dictionary user

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include your relevant source code. This will help the community help you. Also, if you can't for some reason use a database, what data stores do you have available to you? (And why can't you use a database?) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If database is not an option, create a file/directory with the chat ID and store keys. Every time your bot is interacting with this person, check the keys in the file/directory for that user then proceed processing.